# How to set Release configuration in Visual Studio Community edition?

Tags: visual-studio

I am unable to set the solution configuration to Release in the Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. In the dropdown list, there is only the Debug option available.
Does it support Release or do I have to upgrade to  Standard/Enterprise Editions?

Comment: What project is it?

Comment: Try adding a new release configuration using the configuration manager.

Comment: Check your git history for your `.sln` file. SLN files _by default_ define Release and Debug solution-configurations (assuming you have at least 1 project-type that supports build configurations). You should see a commit/change/diff for your `.sln` file where the default configurations were removed for some reason.